# Help with textures disappearing

Tags: texturing

I am currently trying to make VRChat models using MMD bases. I molded a shirt to the model and added a texture but whenever I open it up in my actual model file it has no textures, it just shows up as orange. Im using the "blender render" rending mode because thats how the mmd models seem to come. Any help is appreciated  thank you very much.

Also I know how to use the append feature but I am not sure if I am using it properly, is there a way to keep textures when appending one model into another?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the texture is packed into the file. You can do this by (in the Image or UV Editor) going to Image>Pack As PNG. A star* next to Image means that the image is not packed. [image]

Comment: Not sure how to add an image to posts here but I did the packing as you showed and this is how my shirt looks in its own blender file https://gyazo.com/ad3fd9a43aee5f0ff0205d9b2a45489c
and this is how it looks when I use the append feature to add it into another https://gyazo.com/6a3286085c5a0858ee0a73be7e50791e